# how to change `ari-label` description dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend, web-component, wai-aria

how to change the value of 'ARIA-LABEL` according to user's precise language

```
getLang(element): void {
  let lang = element.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');

  const labelAria = element.document.querySelector('[aria-label]');

  if(lang === 'en'){
   ?????
  }

}
```

Seeem give me some guidance I will be very grateful

Comment: Why are you trying to get with `element.document` ? It's unusual..
Anyway you can set any attribute of an html element with `Element.setAttribute(name, value)` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: thank you very much for the help I will review how you guided me

Comment: And the HTML DOM is just ``document.html``

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by `element.document` but here is the correct way:

```
const labelAria = document.getElementById('element-id');

// set attribute
if(lang === 'en'){
   labelAria.setAttribute('aria-label', 'description here');
}
```

But if you really want to get the element by its aria label:

```
const labelAria = document.querySelector('div[aria-label="description here"]');

// set attribute
if(lang === 'en'){
   labelAria.setAttribute('aria-label', 'description here');
}
```